# How to assign new values to a subset of rows in a Pandas column?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Consider:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3,4),'b':(10,20,30,40),'c':(100,200,300,400)})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3),'b':(10,20,30),'c':(1111,2222,3333)})
```

```
df1:            df2:
    a   b   c           a   b   c
0   1   10  100     0   1   10  1111
1   2   20  200     1   2   20  2222
2   3   30  300     2   3   30  3333
3   4   40  400
```

Do the following operation:

```
df1.set_index(['a', 'b']).loc[df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index, 'c'] = df2.c
```

My expectation of df1 would be:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   10  1111
1   2   20  2222
2   3   30  3333
3   4   40  400
```

The result is:

```
    a   b   c
0   1   10  100
1   2   20  200
2   3   30  300
3   4   40  400
```

Could you please help me to achieve my expected goal and explain my failure?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1.set_index(['a', 'b']).loc[df2.set_index(['a', 'b']).index, 'c']` creates a new DataFrame, to which you assign values and then drop it since it's not assigned to a variable name.

If you have a range index, you can [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) and [`combine_first`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.combine_first.html):

```
out = df1[['a', 'b']].merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='left').combine_first(df1)
```

For an arbitrary index and to assign in place:

```
df1['d'] = (df1[['a', 'b']].reset_index()
            .merge(df2, on=['a', 'b'], how='left')
            .set_index('index')['c']
            .fillna(df1['c'])
           )
```

*NB. this is assuming that there is no duplicated combination of `a`/`b` in `df2`.*

Output:

```
   a   b       c
0  1  10  1111.0
1  2  20  2222.0
2  3  30  3333.0
3  4  40   400.0
```

Comment: Your given reason for my failure is clear. Both of your solution works fine. The first solution seems to work even if df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a':(1,2,3),'b':(10,20,30),'c':(1111,2222,3333)}, index=['x','x','y']). Your precondition of range index might be unnecessary if your merge is based on the 'on=' argument. (I am not entirely sure.) Your N.B. comment was enlightening. Thank you!

Comment: @msg the condition on the index is for `df1` since `merge` resets the index.

Comment: Indeed. And the second solution with the slight modification of (df1['c'] =) still gives the desired result. Perfect.